# Error - CampaignImageId field not found while deploying Profiles to Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx

I am getting the following error while trying to deploy Permission sets and profiles to a scratch org (SFDX):

**`In field: field - no CustomField named Campaign.CampaignImageId found`**

When I looked at the field in production, it's a standard field with Look Up relationship with Content Document.

For some reason, this field is not being created in our Scratch Orgs, hence I am getting above error while trying to deploy Profiles/Permission sets.

Anyone faced this error before and know a workaround?

Comment: Please, check your `package.xml` if it contains such a field. I believe, the problem is connected with the file.
After doing so, please reply to the post with the answer

Comment: It's not showing up in my scratch org either, for what it's worth. I think it might be related to some sort of setting, but I'm not sure what setting that would be.

Comment: I think so too and it's too annoying. Already spent hours in fixing production metadata i.e. getting rid of those additional bits which don't exist in Scratch orgs.

It would have helped if we could create scratch orgs with exact same features what we have in Production. I know there is some Beta feature in the pipeline for Org Shape, but it doesn't help us now.